# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds Java(Now stack overflow error!?)

Tags: java, arrays, exception, stack

I'm trying to write a program that returns yes/no whether or not a maze is traversable but keep getting this exception...what's wrong??  How can I stop this from happening? (I'd like to keep this structure as much as possible)

Maze:

```
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
WSOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWOOOOOOW
WWOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOW
WWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOW
WOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWW
WOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOWWWWWWWWWOWWWWW
WOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWOOOOOWW
WOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOWWWWWWWWWWWWWOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWOOW
WOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOWWWWOOOOOOOOWWWWWWWOOOOOOWWWWWWWWWWWWWWFW
WWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWW
```

New code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.awt.Point;

public class MazeExplorer {
    static Point startPoint = new Point();
    static Point finishPoint = new Point();
    final static int mazeHeight = 12;
    final static int mazeWidth = 58;
    static char[][] mazePoints = new char[mazeHeight][mazeWidth];
    Stack<Point> pointsNotTraversed = new Stack<Point>();
    Point pt = new Point();
    static HashSet<Point> previousLocations = new HashSet<Point>();
    static Stack<Point> nextPoints = new Stack<Point>();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{

        System.out.println("Please enter the file name of your Maze");
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        File f = new File(console.nextLine());
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);

        if(!sc.hasNextLine()){
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter a file name with the extension, that contains a maze!");
        }
        System.out.println("So, you want to know if your maze is solvable.....?");

        for (int row = 0; row < mazeHeight && sc.hasNext(); row++) {
            final String mazeRow = sc.next(); //Get the next row from the scanner.
            mazePoints[row] = mazeRow.toCharArray(); //Convert the row into a char[].
        }
            //identify the finish point
        for(int i = 0; i < mazeHeight; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<mazeWidth; j++){
                if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'F'){
                    finishPoint = new Point(i, j);
                }       
            }
        }
        // Identify the start point
       for(int i = 0; i< mazeHeight; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j < mazeWidth; j++){
               if(mazePoints[i][j] == 'S'){
                 startPoint = new Point(i , j);
               }
           }
       }
       isTraversable(startPoint);    
    }
        public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){
            boolean isSolvable = false;
            nextPoints.push(current);

            do {


                if(current.y < 11) {
                    if((mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] != ' ') && (mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] != 'W') ){ // below direction
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y + 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y + 1][current.x] = ' ';        
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.y > 0){


                if (mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] != 'W' ){ //up dir
                   nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y - 1, current.x));
                    mazePoints[current.y - 1][current.x] = ' ';  //'X' marks where you've already been
                   isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());     

                }
                }
                if(current.x < 57){
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] != 'W'){ // to the right
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x + 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] = ' ';
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.x > 0){


                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] != ' ' && mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] != 'W') { // to the left
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x - 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x - 1] = ' ';     
                    isTraversable(nextPoints.pop());    

                }
                }
                if(current.equals(finishPoint)){
                    isSolvable = true;
                    System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!");
                }




            } while(!current.equals('F') && !nextPoints.isEmpty());    


            return isSolvable;          
        }
}
```

Comment: which statement is causing the error? The exception should give you a line #

Comment: There's been so many maze questions today...

Comment: What's your stack trace?

Comment: @David how can I find out?? Btw, will that help with stack overflow error i get now?

Comment: @bazookyelmo I updated my response. Apologizes. I left off an if/else.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(current.x < 58){
                if(mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] == 'O'){ // to the right
                    nextPoints.push(new Point(current.y, current.x + 1));
                    mazePoints[current.y][current.x + 1] = ' ';
                }
                }
```

when current.x = 57, you would get array index bound exception replace 58 with 57, because u do  current.x + 1 and 58 indx does not exist

Comment: Thank you, changed to 57 and likewise for other problems...now I have a stack overflow error??

Comment: isTraversable calls itself and this causes stack overflow exception u could either first try with lesser number thatn 58 to test your functionlity and then change the isTraversable function from recursive to an iterative function

Comment: How can I do it iteratively..? @PulkitSethi?

Comment: cannot write complete solution for you mate check online for searching algorithm examples

Comment: I've actually solved the stack overflow..but now my program goes infinitely...?  See edit..

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because your recursive method is not properly thought out. I've taken the liberty of cleaning up a bit of the method so you can see what it should look like.

I know recursion can be a tricky topic, but you'll want to understand the code or practice more with recursion if you plan to learn effectively.

```
public static  boolean isTraversable(Point current){
        boolean isSolvable = false;
        mazePoints[current.x][current.y] = ' ';

        if(current.y < 57 && current.y > 0 && current.x > 0 && current.x < 12){
            if (mazePoints[current.x - 1][current.y] == 'O'){ // Up dir
                Point upPoint = new Point(current.x-1, current.y);
                nextPoints.push(upPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x+1][current.y] == 'O'){ // Down dir
                Point downPoint = new Point(current.x+1, current.y);
                nextPoints.push(downPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x][current.y + 1] == 'O'){ // to the right
                Point rightPoint = new Point(current.x, current.y+1);
                nextPoints.push(rightPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x][current.y - 1] == 'O'){ // to the left
                Point leftPoint = new Point(current.x, current.y-1);
                nextPoints.push(leftPoint);
            }

            if(mazePoints[current.x - 1][current.y] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x + 1][current.y] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x][current.y - 1] == 'F' ||
               mazePoints[current.x][current.y + 1] == 'F'){
                System.out.println("MAZE IS SOLVABLE, YAHOOOOOO!!!!");
                return true;
            }

        }

        if(nextPoints.isEmpty()){
            return false;
        }
        else{
            current = nextPoints.pop();
        }

        return(isTraversable(current));

    }
```

Comment: @bazookyelmo I left off an else statement at the end there. That should do it.

Comment: no it wasn't that...I had the wrong maze file! *facepalm* It works perfect with the maze you exemplified with..(which was the correct maze)

Comment: @bazookyelmo Glad I could help. You have 13 questions and have only accepted answers on 3. If they don't have good answers that's fine, but try not to abandon questions without marking the answer that helped if there is one. Best of luck =]

Comment: I'll get on that right away! I'm really more used to forums, so this is new.  Thanks for everything.  One question on the isTraversable method...let's say the maze looked like the one I posted above, how could that be solved? Since it requires the path to retrace the 0 above the F..?

Comment: @bazookyelmo Oops. The if statement was off by one. edited to fix